# Regex to match logfile custom date formats

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I'm trying to parse lines between a date range in a file. However dates are formatted in a non standard way. Is it possible for a regex to match these? The log file is formatted like so:

```
Jan  5 11:34:00 log messages here
Jan 13 16:21:00 log messages here
Feb  1 01:14:00 log messages here
Feb 10 16:32:00 more messages
Mar  7 16:32:00 more messages
Apr 21 16:32:00 more messages
```

For example if I want to match lines between January 1st and Feb 10th, Ive been unable to get regex to match the month order since they arent numerical.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shell line, might do the trick. Assume you want to see the first 41 days after January '2nd', then you can do

**pipeline of `echo`, `date` and `grep`:**

```
echo {0..41} \
  | xargs -I{} -d ' ' date -d "2018-01-02 + {} days" +"%b %e" \
  | grep -F -f - <logfile>
```

I believe this is the quickest. The idea is to build a set of possible days (these are the first two lines), and then search for them with `grep`.

**sorted log-file with `awk`:**

When processing sorted log-files you can use quick-returns to limit yourself to processing the only-needed fractions.

```
awk -v tstart="Jan  1" -v tend="Feb 10" '
   BEGIN{ month["Jan"]=1; month["Feb"]=2; month["Mar"]=3
          month["Arp"]=4; month["May"]=5; month["Jun"]=6
          month["Jul"]=7; month["Aug"]=8; month["Sep"]=9
          month["Oct"]=10;month["Nov"]=11;month["Dec"]=12
          $0=tstart; ms=$1; ds=$2
          $0=tend  ; me=$1; de=$2
         }
  (month[$1]<month[ms])             { next }
  (month[$1]==month[ms]) && ($2<ds) { next }
  (month[$1]==month[me]) && ($2>de) { exit }
  (month[$1]>month[me])             { exit }
  1' <logfile>
```

**unsorted log-file with `awk` :**

When processing unsorted log-files, you need to do the comparisons actively. This obviously takes much more time.

```
awk -v tstart="Jan  1" -v tend="Feb 10" '
   BEGIN{ month["Jan"]=1; month["Feb"]=2; month["Mar"]=3
          month["Arp"]=4; month["May"]=5; month["Jun"]=6
          month["Jul"]=7; month["Aug"]=8; month["Sep"]=9
          month["Oct"]=10;month["Nov"]=11;month["Dec"]=12
          $0=tstart; ms=$1; ds=$2
          $0=tend  ; me=$1; de=$2
         }
   (ms == me) && ($1 == ms) && (ds<=$2) && ($2<=de) { print; next }
   ($1 == ms) && (ds<=$2)                           { print; next }
   ($1 == me) && ($2<=de)                           { print; next }
   (month[ms]<month[$1]) && (month[$1]<month[me])` <logfile>
```

The above commands both return :

```
Jan  5 11:34:00 log messages here
Jan 13 16:21:00 log messages here
Feb  1 01:14:00 log messages here
Feb 10 16:32:00 more messages
```

**note:** date-ranges that cross the 31st of December might give bogus results.

Comment: I was hoping for a regex so that I can use it with awk alternatives such as:
https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

I found awk was too slow for my use case  unfortunately.

Comment: @Sam, a generic regex is not possible as it depends on the ranges. Also regex does not allow numeric comparisons. So for your simple case, the regex would be `Jan +[0-9]+|Feb  [0-9]|Feb 1[0-1]` Every time you do  a different range, you have to build it up. The problem the awk is slow is due to the calls to `date`. I do believe I can spead it up.

Comment: @Sam added an option for sorted files which would probably the best solution. Sadly no regex.

Comment: @Sam, I have found a way to do it with `grep`. This might be your solution to use it with `the_silver_searcher`