# Get log file entries between two dates, only fatal ones

Tags: apache, awk

I searched the web, SO and nothing wants to do the job. 
Given a simple apache logfile like

```
[Fri Jun 22 11:46:13 2018] [error] [client xxxxxxxx] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy on line 3554, referer: wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
[Fri Jun 22 14:09:37 2018] [error] [client xxxxxxxx] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function date_mysql2german() in yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy on line 156, referer: wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
[Mon Jun 25 17:03:37 2018] [error] [client xxxxxxxx] PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy on line 1409, referer: wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
[Tue Jun 26 11:46:26 2018] [error] [client xxxxxxxx] PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy on line 9390, referer: wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
[Tue Jun 26 11:46:26 2018] [error] [client xxxxxxxx] PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy on line 9432, referer: wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

I need to extract all "PHP Warning:" lines (full line) of the last 5 minutes.

Here is what I tried so far

```
awk 
-v Date="$(date "+[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")" \ 
-v Date2="$(date --date="5 minutes ago" "+[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")" \
'$4 > Date && $4 < Date2' /var/log/apache2/apache2/my_log_file.log
```

But even that (without grep for "Warning" e.g.) does not return anything. The pasted log entries and their date/times are just examples - in reality I do have Warnings within the last 5 minutes, so it should definitly return something.

Any ideas on how to change this stuff and get it to work?
Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: You can not simply use a alphanumeric comparison for the date because the year comes at the end in the datestring format of the example log file. alphanumeric comparisons only work when your timeformat is something like `YYYYMMDD...`

Comment: You'll have to parse the timestring into a UNIX timestamp, compare the timestamps + search for FATAL. The first part, converting to UNIX timestamps, can't be done in portable way with awk because only GNU awk (gawk) supports that. I would probably use Python or Perl for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you compare your strings way too literal. The dates are ordered by data, but `awk` compares lexicographical ("Jan" < "Feb" datewise but string wise it is not). There are various approaches that can be taken here, but I suggest to make the comparisons in UNIX epoch time.

```
$ tend=$(date "+%s")
$ tstart=$(date --date="5 minutes ago" "+%s")
$ awk -F '[][]' '!/PHP Warning/{next}
                 { cmd="date --date=\""$2"\" \"+%s\""
                   time=((cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : -1)
                   close(cmd) }
                 (time == -1) { exit 1 }
                 (tend <= time && time <= tstart)
                ' tstart=$tstart tend=$tend <logfile>
```

**note:** this will execute a large number of calls to `date` if your file is big.

A different approach might be calling [`mktime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) from GNU awk or reformatting your time string as *yyyymmddHHMMSS*. This allows you to use lexicographical ordering for strings :

```
$ tstart=$(date -d="5 minutes ago" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"")
$ tend=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"")
$ awk 'BEGIN{ month["Jan"]="01"; month["Feb"]="02"; month["Mar"]="03"
            month["Arp"]="04"; month["May"]="05"; month["Jun"]="06"
            month["Jul"]="07"; month["Aug"]="08"; month["Sep"]="09"
            month["Oct"]="10"; month["Nov"]="11"; month["Dec"]="12" }
      !/PHP Warning/{next}
      { time=$4; gsub(/:/,"",time); year=substr($5,1,4);
        date=sprintf(%4s%2s%0.2d%6s,year,month[$2],$3,time) }
      }
      (tstart <= date && tend <= date)
     ' tend=$tend tstart=$tstart  <logfile>
```

Or per suggestion of [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045629/get-log-file-entries-between-two-dates-only-fatal-ones/51046746#comment89086396_51046746):

```
$ awk '!/PHP Warning/{next}
       { year=substr($5,1,4)
         month=(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$2)+2)/3
         time=$4; gsub(/:/,"",time);
         date=sprintf(%4s%0.2d%0.2d%6s,year,month,$3,time)
       }
       (tstart <= date && tend <= date)
      ' tend=$end tstart=$tstart <logfile>
```

A related post can be found here: [Regex to match logfile custom date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751362/regex-to-match-logfile-custom-date-formats)

Answer (score 1):

This worked in bash + gawk for me:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

LC_ALL=C gawk -v limit=$(date --date="5 minutes ago" "+%s") '
function epoch(month, day, hhmmss, year) {
    gsub(/:/, " ", hhmmss)
    sub(/\]/, "", year)
    month = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", month) + 2) / 3
    return mktime(year" "month" "day" "hhmmss)
}
/PHP Warning/ && epoch($2, $3, $4, $5) > limit
' "test.log"
```

If you want to include fatal errors as well, just remove `/PHP Warning/ &&` or adjust the regex as desired (e.g. `/Warning|error/` or similar).